# How to install the WASP in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to use WASP plug-in in powershell. Lack of knowledge about c#, I have no idea how to install it. I have downloaded the archive file from https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=wasp . I haven't found a "install" file in the zip. There is no user guide for installation on the page, either. I would like to install it from powershell. My system is windows10, 64bits. I need some help, thank you.

Comment: [add ps snapin](https://ss64.com/ps/add-pssnapin.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can use SendKeys directly via PowerShell.

```
# Example, start notepad, grab all services and display in in notepad using SendKeys
Notepad 
Get-Service | Clip
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
## .NET:
[void][reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("system.windows.forms")
[system.windows.forms.sendkeys]::sendwait('^v')
```

Yet, WASP and other tools like if are better options. However, WASP is a very old project and has not been maintained in years. I have it as do many other and used it in the past. From CodePlex, you need Visual Studio [( you can use the free community edition)](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) to compile that into a DLL to be imported. Yet again , it's very old. So, there are other tools to use for GUI automatization vs WASP.

***See:***

[PowerShell module to run a Selenium WebDriver.](https://github.com/adamdriscoll/selenium-powershell)

[PowerShell & Selenium: Automate Web Browser Interactions](https://tech.mavericksevmont.com/blog/powershell-selenium-automate-web-browser-interactions-part-i)

[PowerShell, Selenium and Browser Automation](https://www.alkanesolutions.co.uk/blog/2018/12/06/powershell-selenium-and-browser-automation)

AutoIt Cmdlets for Windows PowerShell

https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/187775-run-powershell-script-with-autoit
https://www.autoitconsulting.com/site/scripting/autoit-cmdlets-for-windows-powershell

Comment: Thank you very much of clarifying the shortage of WASP. I don't have a visual Studio. I will try your advices!